# Copying a MySQL 5.6 server settings for a new environment?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have a MySQL 5.6 Server running on a Windows 8 VM on a steel case server.  It's been having issues (The Windows 8, which is then causing the MySQL to have issues).  Therefore I was tasked with putting the MySQL 5.6 Server on a Windows 10 VM for stability reasons.  The amount of ram the server is allowed and other settings have been tweaked over time.  Is there an way I can export these settings, so when I install MySQL on my Windows 10 VM, I can just tell it to use the same?

Answer (score 0):

The first recommendation is to not use Windows 10 on your installation if this is for a production server. I highly recommend you Linux but if that's not possible at least Windows Server.

Asking your question, YES.

Just install MySQL (same version as on old machine) and follow these steps

- Stop MySQL on both machines (New and old)
- Locate and delete datadir folder on the new machine and copy the one from the old machine
- Do the same with my.ini file (Delete the new one and replace it with old one).

In theory, you should be able to start MySQL on the new machine and access the data.

Check data and if everything goes fine, you can delete old machine service/data.